# How to add a separator in this sector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/t85rfcg9/1/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<input id="date_of_birth" type="text" value="23091992" maxlength="8">
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$( "#date_of_birth" ).keyup(function() {
    var str=$(this).val();
    var day_str=str.substring(0,2);
    var month_str=str.substring(2,3);
    console.log(day_str);
    console.log(month_str);
});
```

I have a input with the following value

```
23091992
```

What I want to do after you run the script, my text to have the following format.

```
23/09/1992
```

I tried to share my strong two and add a separator, but unfortunately I can not manage ...
Please can you help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you use datepicker for this field?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake, immediately edit

Comment: @Marius Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. But instead, you can use:

```
<input type="date" />
```

Or there are hell lot of datepicker plugins available. Still if you would like to do this way, then this is the solution:

```
$( "#date_of_birth" ).keyup(function() {
    var str=$(this).val();
    var day_str=str.substring(0,2);
    var month_str=str.substring(2,4);
    var year_str=str.substring(4,8);
    console.log(day_str);
    console.log(month_str);
    console.log(year_str);
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 8)
        $(this).val(day_str + "/" + month_str + "/" + year_str);
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$("#date_of_birth").keyup(function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  var day_str = str.substring(0, 2);
  var month_str = str.substring(2, 4);
  var year_str = str.substring(4, 8);
  console.log(day_str);
  console.log(month_str);
  console.log(year_str);
  if ($(this).val().trim().length == 8)
    $(this).val(day_str + "/" + month_str + "/" + year_str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date_of_birth" type="text" value="23091992" maxlength="8">
Press up or down. Trigger a keyup.
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufzr9hcm/**

Answer (score 0):

You should use date picker of course or some js masking for inputs,
but ... check this

```
$("#date_of_birth").keyup(function() {
  var t = $(this),
      inpVal = t.val();

  //clean from previous / slashes
  inpVal = inpVal.replace(/\//g, ''); 

  t.val(inpVal);

  // check if 8 digits entered (2day, 2month, 4year)
  if (inpVal.length == 8) { 
    var day_str = inpVal.substring(0, 2),
      month_str = inpVal.substring(2, 4),
      year_str = inpVal.substring(4),
      formDate = day_str + "/" + month_str + "/" + year_str;
    t.val(formDate);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Assumptions

1. Year will always be of 4 digits.
2. Date format is `DDMMYYYY`
3. If date + month string length is even i.e. 2 or 4, then value is divided equally.
4. If length is `3`, check if last 2 digits <= 12. If yes, consider it as month, else first 2 as day and last as month.

#### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/17u1xx05/2/).

```js
function getFormattedDate(date, seperator) {
  var len = date.length;
  var year = date.substring(len - 4);
  var monthAndDate = date.substring(0, len - 4);
  var day, month;

  if (!seperator) {
    seperator = "/";
  }

  switch (monthAndDate.length) {
    case 2:
      day = monthAndDate.charAt(0);
      month = monthAndDate.charAt(1);
      break;
    case 3:
      if (parseInt(monthAndDate.substring(1)) <= 12) {
        day = monthAndDate.charAt(0);
        month = monthAndDate.substring(1);
      } else {
        day = monthAndDate.substring(0, 2);
        month = monthAndDate.charAt(2);
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      day = monthAndDate.substring(0, 2);
      month = monthAndDate.substring(2);
      break;
  }
  return day + seperator + month + seperator + year;
}

(function() {
  var date = "23091992";
  console.log(getFormattedDate(date, "/"));

  date = "1111992";
  console.log(getFormattedDate(date, "-"));

  date = "111992"
  console.log(getFormattedDate(date));
})()
```